# Can I make an optional input required, if another optional input is present?

Tags: bixby

I'm writing an action that is collecting three inputs. The first is required, but the second and third are optional. Because the second and third options are of similar Types, sometimes the third type is filled while the second is left unfilled.

*i.e., I want to pass in a book, or book + page, or book + page + line number*

I can obviously handle this by making multiple (nearly identical) actions, or in the endpoint itself, but is it possible to make a single actions input's dependency determined by the presence of another input?

Action currently looks something like...

```
collect {
  input (book) {
    type (String)
    min (Required) max (One)
  }
  input (page) {
    type (Integer)
    min (Optional) max (One)
  }
  input (line) {
    type (Integer)
    min (Optional) max (One)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the best option (and only I've been able to find so far) is to create modify the original, then add a second. Finally, add a new `action-endpoint` to `endpoints`.

**ReadBook** removes the *optional* Line

```
action (ReadBook) {
  description ("Read a page from a book (first if page isn't provided)."")
  type (Calculation)
  collect {
    input (book) {
      type (Book)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    input (page) {
      type (PageNum)
      min (Optional) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (Passage)
}
```

**ReadBookLine** makes all inputs *required*

```
action (ReadBookLine) {
  description (Read a line from a book.)
  type (Calculation)
  collect {
    input (book) {
      type (Book)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    input (page) {
      type (PageNum)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
    input (line) {
      type (LineNum)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }
  output (Passage)
}
```

**Endpoints**

```
endpoints {
    action-endpoint (ReadBook) {
      accepted-inputs (book, page)
      remote-endpoint ("https://.../read_book) {
        method (POST)
      }
    }
    action-endpoint (ReadBookLine) {
      accepted-inputs (book, page, line)
      remote-endpoint ("https://.../read_book") {
        method (POST)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your use case, it would make sense to use `default-init` in the following way:

```
collect {
  input (book) {
    type (String)
    min (Required) max (One)
  }
  input (page) {
    type (Integer)
    min (Optional) max (One)
    default-init {
      if (!exists(page)) {
        intent {
          goal: YOUR ACTION HERE
          value: Integer (1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  input (line) {
    type (Integer)
    min (Optional) max (One)
    default-init {
      if (!exists(line)) {
        intent {
          goal: YOUR ACTION HERE
          value: Integer (1)
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow for the page and line numbers to default to 1 if they have not been provided by the user.

Comment: They're *optional*. I don't want the default to be one (because if `line` isn't supplied, I'll return the entire page). I don't even want the default to be `null` (though that could work. Is that possible?)... I want the input to not be set to anything (i.e., *optional*).

Comment: I could use `0` in my case. But probably not a good *generic* answer (as zero might be a possible answer for others looking for a similar answer).

Comment: Ah I see. You could use `-1` as a special case in your `default-init` and handle that value in your Action so that it returns the whole page if the `line` isn't provided and defaults to `-1`.